# Why doesn't Delete work in Android Room even though the data to be deleted matches the primary key?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am receiving data from my remote server to synchronize the local database in Room with the remote database (MySQL).

In the case of DELETE it does not work, even though the data received has matching rows that should be deleted.

It should be noted that the table has a primary key composed of the columns `groupFK` and `readingFK`.

I show the relevant part of the code.

#### Entity

```
@Entity(
    tableName = Constants.LH_PSALM_JOIN,
    primaryKeys = ["groupFK", "readingFK"],
    foreignKeys =
    [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = LHPsalmodyJoinEntity::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("groupID"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("groupFK"),
            onDelete = CASCADE,
            onUpdate = CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = LHPsalmEntity::class,
            parentColumns = arrayOf("psalmID"),
            childColumns = arrayOf("readingFK"),
            onDelete = CASCADE,
            onUpdate = CASCADE
        ), ForeignKey(
        entity = LHThemeEntity::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("themeID"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("themeFK"),
        onDelete = SET_NULL,
        onUpdate = CASCADE
    ), ForeignKey(
        entity = EpigraphEntity::class,
        parentColumns = arrayOf("epigraphID"),
        childColumns = arrayOf("epigraphFK"),
        onDelete = SET_NULL,
        onUpdate = CASCADE
    )]
)
data class LHPsalmJoinEntity(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "groupFK", index = true)
    var groupFK: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "readingFK", index = true)
    var readingFK: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "theOrder")
    var theOrder: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "themeFK", defaultValue = "NULL", index = true)
    var themeFK: Int?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "epigraphFK", defaultValue = "NULL", index = true)
    var epigraphFK: Int?,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "thePart", defaultValue = "NULL")
    var thePart: Int?
)
```

#### Class in external layer

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class LHPsalmJoin(
    val groupFK:Int,
    val readingFK:Int,
    val theOrder:Int,
    val themeFK:Int?=null,
    val epigraphFK:Int?=null,
    val thePart:Int?=null,
)
```

#### Delete method in DAO

```
@Delete(entity = LHPsalmJoinEntity::class)
fun lhPsalmJoinDeleteAll(d: List<LHPsalmJoin>):Int
```

#### Call in CRUD class

```
/* d is declared as List<LHPsalmJoin>
   and filled with data to delete
   see image
*/
val count=mDao.lhPsalmJoinDeleteAll(d)
println("Deleted rows: $count") //Is always 0
```

I'm receiving into `d` data that should be deleted, as can be seen in the following screenshot:

[image]

And in the database there are matching rows, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

But nothing happens, when I call `lhPsalmJoinDeleteAll()`, the value of `count` is `0` and the row that should be deleted in the database remains.

The row is deleted if I manually execute the query:

```
delete from lh_psalm_join 
where 
    groupFK=901110201 and 
    readingFK=181;
```

I don't understand then why it doesn't delete  using the list. The idea is to be able to delete one or more rows, which is why a manual query is not useful for me.

Answer (score 1):

This may well be a bug.

> The row is deleted if I manually execute the query: `delete from lh_psalm_join  where  groupFK=901110201 and  readingFK=181;`

> The idea is to be able to delete one or more rows, which is why a manual query is not useful for me.

It could be useful. Consider:-

```
@Query("DELETE FROM ${Constants.LH_PSALM_JOIN} WHERE groupFK=:groupFK AND readingFK=:readingFK")
fun delete(groupFK: Int, readingFK:Int)
@Transaction
@Query("")
fun deleteMany(list: List<LHPsalmJoin>) {
    for (p in list) {
        delete(p.groupFK,p.readingFK)
    }
}
```

- i.e. **your query** and another function that invokes that (now useful) query.

Perhaps consider the following demonstration (based upon your code adapted (FK definitions commented out)):-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        val plist1 = listOf<LHPsalmJoin>(
            LHPsalmJoin(901110201,181,1,null,1,1)
            ,LHPsalmJoin(901110201,182,1,null,1,1)
            ,LHPsalmJoin(901110201,183,1,null,1,1)
            ,LHPsalmJoin(901110201,184,1,null,1,1)
        )
        val plist2 = listOf<LHPsalmJoin>(
            LHPsalmJoin(901110202,181,1,null,1,1)
            ,LHPsalmJoin(901110202,182,1,null,1,1)
            ,LHPsalmJoin(901110202,183,1,null,1,1)
            ,LHPsalmJoin(901110202,184,1,null,1,1)
        )
        dao.insert(plist1)
        dao.insert(plist2)
        logAllPsalms()
        dao.lhPsalmJoinDeleteAll(plist1)
        logAllPsalms()
        dao.deleteMany(plist1)
        logAllPsalms()
    }
    fun logAllPsalms() {
        val p = dao.getAllLHPSALMJOINS()
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        for (p in dao.getAllLHPSALMJOINS()) {
            sb.append("\n\tGRPFK=${p.groupFK} RDFK=${p.readingFK} ....")
        }
        Log.d("DBINFO","${p.size} LHPSALMS extracted. They are:-${sb}")
    }
}
```

When run the log includes:-

```
2023-11-04 06:58:01.646 D/DBINFO: 8 LHPSALMS extracted. They are:-
        GRPFK=901110201 RDFK=181 ....
        GRPFK=901110201 RDFK=182 ....
        GRPFK=901110201 RDFK=183 ....
        GRPFK=901110201 RDFK=184 ....
        GRPFK=901110202 RDFK=181 ....
        GRPFK=901110202 RDFK=182 ....
        GRPFK=901110202 RDFK=183 ....
        GRPFK=901110202 RDFK=184 ....
        
        
2023-11-04 06:58:01.662 D/DBINFO: 8 LHPSALMS extracted. They are:-
        GRPFK=901110201 RDFK=181 ....
        GRPFK=901110201 RDFK=182 ....
        GRPFK=901110201 RDFK=183 ....
        GRPFK=901110201 RDFK=184 ....
        GRPFK=901110202 RDFK=181 ....
        GRPFK=901110202 RDFK=182 ....
        GRPFK=901110202 RDFK=183 ....
        GRPFK=901110202 RDFK=184 ....
        
        
2023-11-04 06:58:01.672 D/DBINFO: 4 LHPSALMS extracted. They are:-
        GRPFK=901110202 RDFK=181 ....
        GRPFK=901110202 RDFK=182 ....
        GRPFK=901110202 RDFK=183 ....
        GRPFK=901110202 RDFK=184 ....
```

- The first section shows that the 2 sets of data (plist1 and then plist2) have been inserted (and using the POJO and along with the entity coded, as is also used in the mass delete which does not appear to work)
- The second section is after the delete with a list, and shows that it, like your experience, is not working and deletes nothing
- The third section shows that the provided alternative delete (deleteMany) with the exact same list does perform the deletions.

Of course if you wanted to delete all rows you could simply use `DELETE FROM the_table` (i.e. no WHERE clause).

If the count of the number of rows deleted is important then you could instead (or as well as) use:-

```
@Delete
fun delete(lhPsalmJoinEntity: LHPsalmJoinEntity): Int
@Transaction
@Query("")
fun deleteManyV2(list: List<LHPsalmJoin>): Int {
    var count=0
    for (p in list) count += delete(LHPsalmJoinEntity(p.groupFK, p.readingFK, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    return count
}
```

- noting that it is just the primary key values that matter when using `@Delete`.

Adding the following code to the demo:-

```
    Log.d("DBINFO","V2 Delete deleted ${dao.deleteManyV2(plist2)} rows.")
    logAllPsalms()
```

- note delete as per plist2 (the remaining rows)

Results in:-

```
2023-11-04 07:23:35.464 D/DBINFO: V2 Delete deleted 4 rows.
2023-11-04 07:23:35.469 D/DBINFO: 0 LHPSALMS extracted. They are:-
```

**Additional**

> My idea was to use as little code as possible, since I have to do CRUD operations with more than 200 tables. Maybe it's a bug with composite primary keys? I haven't had time to try delete operations with tables with a simple primary key.

The very same, non-deletion, occurs with a single column primary key.

i.e using:-

```
@Entity(
tableName = Constants.LH_PSALM_JOIN,
primaryKeys = ["groupFK"/*, "readingFK"*/] ....
```

However, by using

(1) a modified LHPsalmJoin as per:-

```
data class LHPsalmJoin(
    val groupFK:Int,
    val readingFK:Int,
    val theOrder:Int,
    val themeFK:Int?=null,
    val epigraphFK:Int?=null,
    val thePart:Int?=null,
) {
    fun convertToLHPsalmJoinEntity(): LHPsalmJoinEntity {
        return LHPsalmJoinEntity(this.groupFK,this.readingFK,this.theOrder,this.themeFK,this.epigraphFK,this.thePart)
    }
    companion object {
        fun convertListLHPsalmJoinToLHPsalmJoinEntity(list: List<LHPsalmJoin>): List<LHPsalmJoinEntity> {
            val rv = arrayListOf<LHPsalmJoinEntity>()
            for (p in list) rv.add(p.convertToLHPsalmJoinEntity())
            return rv
        }
    }
}
```

(2) The following function in the `@Dao` annotated interface:-

```
@Delete
fun lhPsalmJoinEntityDeleteAll(d: List<LHPsalmJoinEntity>): Int
```

(3) The following additional activity code:-

```
        dao.insert((plist1))
        dao.insert(plist2)
        logAllPsalms()
        dao.lhPsalmJoinEntityDeleteAll(LHPsalmJoin.convertListLHPsalmJoinToLHPsalmJoinEntity(plist1))
        logAllPsalms()
```

Then the deletions are performed:-

```
2023-11-04 08:15:02.587 D/DBINFO: 0 LHPSALMS extracted. They are:-
2023-11-04 08:15:02.595 D/DBINFO: 8 LHPSALMS extracted. They are:-
        GRPFK=901110201 RDFK=181 ....
        GRPFK=901110202 RDFK=182 ....
        GRPFK=901110203 RDFK=183 ....
        GRPFK=901110204 RDFK=184 ....
        GRPFK=901110205 RDFK=181 ....
        GRPFK=901110206 RDFK=182 ....
        GRPFK=901110207 RDFK=183 ....
        GRPFK=901110208 RDFK=184 ....
2023-11-04 08:15:02.601 D/DBINFO: 4 LHPSALMS extracted. They are:-
        GRPFK=901110205 RDFK=181 ....
        GRPFK=901110206 RDFK=182 ....
        GRPFK=901110207 RDFK=183 ....
        GRPFK=901110208 RDFK=184 ....
```

- note that the groupFK values have been changed so they are unique (this to accommodate the single column primary key)

  - exactly the same results when reinstating the composite primary key.

The following is the generated Java for both:-

```
  @Override
  public int lhPsalmJoinDeleteAll(final List<LHPsalmJoin> d) {
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    int _total = 0;
    __db.beginTransaction();
    try {
      _total +=__deletionAdapterOfLHPsalmJoinAsLHPsalmJoinEntity.handleMultiple(d);
      __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
      return _total;
    } finally {
      __db.endTransaction();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int lhPsalmJoinEntityDeleteAll(final List<LHPsalmJoinEntity> d) {
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    int _total = 0;
    __db.beginTransaction();
    try {
      _total +=__deletionAdapterOfLHPsalmJoinEntity.handleMultiple(d);
      __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
      return _total;
    } finally {
      __db.endTransaction();
    }
  }
```

i.e. they are identical and it is obviously the handling of `+=__deletionAdapterOfLHPsalmJoinEntity.handleMultiple(d);` where the issue lays.

Which utilises:-

```
  private final EntityDeletionOrUpdateAdapter<LHPsalmJoinEntity> __deletionAdapterOfLHPsalmJoinEntity;

  private final EntityDeletionOrUpdateAdapter<LHPsalmJoin> __deletionAdapterOfLHPsalmJoinAsLHPsalmJoinEntity;
```

As such it is the handling by `androidx.room.EntityDeletionOrUpdateAdapter;`'s `handleMultiple` method that is not handling the `List<LHPSalmJoin>` as would be expected as per ***If the target entity is specified via entity then the parameters can be of arbitrary POJO types that will be interpreted as partial entities. For example:*** from https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Delete

Comment: Thank you for this very detailed response. My idea was to use as little code as possible, since I have to do CRUD operations with more than 200 tables. Maybe it's a bug with composite primary keys? I haven't had time to try delete operations with tables with a simple primary key.

Comment: @A.Cedano exactly the same with single column primary key (just a matter of commenting out the second column and then using unique groupFK values).